# Writing to TFileStream

Tags: delphi

Trying to write characters to `TFileStream`. Got three garbage characters in file. What I do wrong?

```
var sss: AnsiString;
var S : TFileStream;
S := TFileStream.Create(FileName,fmCreate);
S.Position := S.Size;
sss := '444';
S.Write(sss,3);
S.Free;
```

Comment: You are writing the address. You need to write the contents of the address. Pass PByte(sss)^ to Write

Comment: On a side note: `S.Position := S.Size;` is useless in this example and can be omitted, as `fmCreate` creates a blank file, so `S.Size` will be 0, and `S.Position` already begins at 0. If you want to *append* to an existing file, use `fmReadWrite` instead of `fmCreate`.

Answer (score 5):

An `AnsiString` is implemented as a *pointer* to its character data. `Write()` takes a `var` reference to the data to write. As such, you are writing the pointer itself to your file, not the characters that are being pointed at.

You need to dereference the pointer (ie index into the string) to get a reference to the 1st character, eg:

```
S.Write(sss[1], Length(sss));
```

Alternatively:

```
S.Write(PAnsiChar(sss)^, Length(sss));
```

That being said, Delphi 2009 and later have a [`TStreamWriter`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter) class that makes this task easier:

```
var S : TStreamWriter;
S := TStreamWriter.Create(FileName);
S.Write('444');
S.Free;
```